# How to include an executable file in setup.py

Tags: python, executable, setup.py, pypi

I have a Python project that uses an executable file.

The package structure is something like that:

```
/Project
    /Package
        __init__.py
        aClass.py
        executableFile
    LICENSE
    README.md
```

and I've this setup.py:

```
...
setup(
    author=...
    author_email=....
    classifiers=[...]
    description=....
    install_requires=[...]
    license=..
    long_description=...
    include_package_data=True
    packages=find_packages(include=['Package*'])
    url=..
    version=x.x.x
)
```

but when I upload the package as stated [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) with twine in PyPI, the executable file is not loaded.

How can I properly include that file in the package?

PS: I've also read about adding scripts=[..] in setup.py, but it is limited to python files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [manifest](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html).

In `MANIFEST.in`:

`include Package/executableFile`

Comment: I've added the MANIFEST.in with the inclusion of the executable under the Project folder and the 'include_package_data=True' in the setup(), but still the executable file does not appear in the package..

Comment: @Frank [This](https://tom-christie.github.io/articles/pypi/) might be of use to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo naming the MANIFEST.in. Now it's fine. However, thank you for the link :)

Comment: @Frank I get the same issue, can you please share more details regarding to the solution ?